# Using LibreOffice SDK to convert files from docx to doc

Tags: cmd, sdk, type-conversion, docx, libreoffice

I'm trying to use the LibreOffice SDK to convert a .doc file in a .docx one.
Unfortunately in my project I can't use the LibreOffice commands and call from cmd:

```
libreoffice7.0.3 --headless --convert-to docx --outdir /u/user/doc_folder /u/user/doc_folder/old_office/file.doc
```

so I need to use directly the SDK.
The problem is that the doc seems not to be very clear or probably I'm not searching well.

In this [link](https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/DevelopersGuide/examples.html#FirstSteps) there is the Developer Guide and in particular, in the "Desktop Environment Example" section there is a Desk example, which should shows how to convert a file.

However, the example code doesn't show anything of this. ([link](https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/DevelopersGuide/OfficeDev/DesktopEnvironment/Desk.java) to the example code)

Comment: You are digging too deep and in the wrong direction. To accomplish this task, you only need one parameter for reading and writing the document - FilterName. For the old .doc it could be "MS Word 97", for the new .docx it could be "MS Word 2007 XML".

Comment: @JohnSUN may you be more specific please?

Comment: The operation of converting a document assumes that you load the document into memory, specifying what type of document you are going to deal with. Then (perhaps after making some changes in the body of the document - not necessary), the document must be saved by specifying the format for saving. The last parameter in [.loadComponentFromURL](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XComponentLoader.html#loadComponentFromURL) and in storeAsURL (or storeToURL) allows you to specify a FilterName.

Comment: Perhaps this [starting point](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Integrating_Import_and_Export_Filters) will be useful